# Mule - web service consumer side security

Tags: mule

Via Mule I'm going to call a web service. For this what kind of security mechanisms exists. I have referred to the mulesoft.org but I could only find security reference from the point of creating web service based app.

I'm going to call a Restfull WS using JSON

Comment: Are you saying the remote web service will be secured? If yes, how? HTTP Basic Auth? Other?

Comment: For example does mule support oauth if the server producing the services needs oauth support

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own cloud connector to consume the API, it is easy to do and it provides you OOTB support for both OAuth 1.0 and 2.0

Here some useful link to get started:
http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/DEVKIT/Your+First+Cloud+Connector
http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/DEVKIT/Authorizing+your+Connector+with+OAuth+2.0